# How do I search a partitioned window function in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

Scenario:
Identify a students first class with the university and determine if they passed a second (consecutive) class after passing the first class with in 1 year of ending the first class. If the student did not pass a consecutive second class within 1 year of ending the first class, did they pass any other classes within the same timeframe, e.g. third, fourth, fifth class.

Questions stemming from the first portion of the scenario were easy enough to answer with the use of the lead() function to pull up the next consecutive class information to the same row as the first class. However, I am having trouble finding the best way to determine if the student passed any classes within the designated timeframe, i.e. within 1 year of ending the first class.

My Question:
Is there a way to perform a lookup/search within the partition created by the lead() function?
OR
Is it better to create an additional aggregated query based on passing grades and join back to the primary table based on the aforementioned date range and appropriate key(s) using WHERE EXISTS?

Thanks for taking a look...

Comment: This looks a lot like you are asking for *homework help*. Such questions must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) What have you tried to answer this question yourself so far? What about the articles/documentation you read didn't you understand? You can find more information on how to ask a homework question in the FAQ: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/2029983)

Comment: Even if it's not homework, we need to see a [mcve], which for SQL questions means we need sample data and expected output, preferably as `CREATE` `INSERT` statements

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I wasn't trying to be unclear and will add some sample code and expected output to better inform. Again, I appreciate the feedback. And this is not a homework question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the question isn't very clear. So I guessed and came up with this.

```
CREATE TABLE Class (
    Id        int   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ExamDate  date  NOT NULL,
    PassMark  float NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Thing (
    Id        int   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    StudentId int   NOT NULL,
    ClassId   int   NOT NULL,
    Score     float     NULL,

    CONSTRAINT Thing_FK_Class FOREIGN KEY (ClassId) REFERENCES Class(Id)
)

;
WITH ctePasses AS (
    -- Get the passes and order them.
    SELECT t.*, c.ExamDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentId ORDER BY c.ExamDate) AS n
    FROM Thing t
        INNER JOIN Class c ON t.ClassId = c.Id
    WHERE ISNULL(t.Score, 0) >= c.PassMark
),
cteIntermediateFails AS (
    -- For every student that has a pass get the number of fails that come after it until either the end of the next pass.
    SELECT t.StudentId, p.n, COUNT(*) AS IntermediateFails
    FROM Thing t
        INNER JOIN Class c ON t.ClassId = c.Id
        INNER JOIN ctePasses p ON t.StudentId = p.StudentId
        LEFT JOIN ctePasses q ON p.StudentId = q.StudentId AND p.n + 1 = q.n        
    WHERE c.ExamDate > p.ExamDate AND c.ExamDate < q.ExamDate
    GROUP BY t.StudentId, p.n
)
SELECT p1.StudentId, p1.ExamDate, p2.ExamDate, f.IntermediateFails
FROM ctePasses p1
    LEFT JOIN ctePasses p2 ON p1.StudentId = p2.StudentId AND p2.n = p1.n + 1
    LEFT JOIN cteIntermediateFails f ON p1.StudentId = f.StudentId AND p1.n = f.n
WHERE p1.n = 1
```

Using CTEs rather than subqueries lets me use the first one in the second one.